# Join two tables on different databases

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have following databases:

1. `test`

   ```
   table1
     fields: id, password, name, lastname
   ```
2. `test2`

   ```
   table2
     fields: id
   ```

How to select `test` and `test2` where `table1` have `id` in `test2.table2.id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried it? You just write the database name `test2.dbo.tblFoo`, though you may need to declare an alias (just write a word after writing the actual name). And the account will obviously need permissions to both DBs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT /* stuff */
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use some functionality in ORM, [Hibernate Shards](https://www.hibernate.org/414.html) for example.