# Join tables from two databases in C#

Tags: c#, database, join

With SQL Server I run this query with no problem...

```
SELECT SUM(Esi) AS Dispo 
FROM [mdb].[dbo].[Query1] AS A
  INNER JOIN [mdb2].[dbo].[TieCol] as B ON A.Alias=B.IDAlias 
WHERE Alias LIKE 'SETUP%'
```

I join two tables that reside in two different databases (`mdb` and `mdb2`).

But how can I do it in my .NET application?
When I need to use this statement

```
string cmdText = "SELECT SUM(Esi) AS Dispo 
                  FROM [mdb].[dbo].[Query1] AS A
                    INNER JOIN [mdb2].[dbo].[TieCol] as B ON A.Alias=B.IDAlias 
                  WHERE Alias LIKE 'SETUP%'";

this.OP = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mdb2"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, this.OP);
```

I can't execute it, since `this.OP` is the connection to `mdb2`... And for `mdb`?

How can I connect to both databases simultanously?

Comment: Permissions? Are you using the same user id when logging into sql server?

Comment: You need to check this question :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408686/how-to-join-two-table-different-database

Comment: Could you try putting a `USE mdb2` before the query you run directly on SQL Server? Does it still work?

Comment: as long as both the databases are on the same server and the same user has rights to both the DBs, it shud work. You dont need to open two connections.

Answer (score 3):

The SQL connection is to the server - the Initial catalog in a connection string behaves like `use` - it sets the default DB.

So your 3 part SQL query should work *as is*. So possibly

1. Make sure that the SQL login used by your app (or the account of your AppPool if using Web and Integrated Security) has the necessary access to both databases. (use RunAs on SQL Enterprise Manager as this account and try to run the query)
2. You might try escaping `[Alias]`
3. Also, if there is coupling between `mdb1` and `mdb2` (e.g. `SPROCS` in `mdb1` use tables in `mdb2` etc), for ease of maintenance, you might consider adding views in `mdb1` for `mdb2` objects. This allows for easy identification of cross-database dependencies. In this case, your query can use views which look like they are in the same database, although the underlying dependency on `mdb2` is still there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this within the connection string. But you can probably do it using a four part reference to the table: `[server].[database].[table].[column]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your C# application only need to connect to one database server for this query.
Say your C# application connect to [mdb]. Database [mdb2] should b linked server in database [mdb].

Since you can run that query in sql server, so there must be one sql server connected to both databases. use that sql server in your C# connection string. That's it!